# lxde-pi-rc.xml empty

Tags: rdp

today I got my new Pi 2. I installed it, and installed xrdp. The problem I'm having is that lxde-pi-rc.xml is empty, does anybody have a link to the code so I could paste it in there. I haven't been able to find the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I created a new user on the PI, and deleted the Pi user. After that I created the Pi user again, and it had a GUI!